# Referencing a field from a query in DoCmd.OpenReport Wherecondition argument

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a command button to open a report with a filter applied by a query. This is so that I can filter the report by the value of a field in a subreport of the parent report, otherwise the filter criteria would be more straightforward.
I have set my `Wherecondition` as follows:

```
Private Sub CmdOpenReport_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptName", , , CategoryID = [Queries].[qryFltrRptByCat]!CategoryID
End Sub
```

When I click the button, I get the following error message:

> Run-time error '2465'
>
> Microsoft Access can't find the field referred to in your expression.

What is the proper syntax to refer to the field in the query?

The query looks for a value in the subform and finds the matching `CategoryID` for the subform value. This is because the data in the subform has a many-to-one relationship with the `CategoryID` in the parent form.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reference tables or queries directly like that. Use DLookup(). Or refer to control on form. Must concatenate variable to literal string, don't forget quote marks:

`DoCmd.OpenReport "rptName", , , "CategoryID = " & Me.CategoryID`

Answer (score 0):

If the `CategoryID` is in a active form and a string you can use:

```
Docmd.OpenReport "rptName", , , "CategoryID = '" & Me.CategoryID & "'"
```

If the `CategoryID` is in a active form and a integer/double you can use:

```
Docmd.OpenReport "rptName", , , "CategoryID = " & Me.CategoryID
```

If the `CategoryID` is in the mainform but the subform is active you can use:

```
Docmd.OpenReport "rptName", , , "CategoryID = " & Me.Parent.CategoryID
```

And you always can use a total reference:

```
Docmd.OpenReport "rptName", , , "CategoryID = " & Forms!YourForm!CategoryID
```

You can look [here](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm) for further informations: